Prevent ckeditor 5 from automatically changing html structure
I use ckeditor 5 and have a problem when ckeditor 5 changes the html structure automatically
How can I preserve the original html structure.
Here is config:
...
import { Schema } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine';

const textarea = document.getElementById(elementId);

    ClassicEditor
      .create(textarea, {
        toolbar: {
             items: [
                'undo', 'redo',
                'findAndReplace', '|',
                'heading', '|',
                'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'removeFormat', '|',
                'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList',
                '-',
                'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontColor', '|',
                'alignment', '|',
                'link', 'imageInsert', 'insertTable', '|',
                'sourceEditing', 'fullScreen',
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
          AutoLink, Link,
          BlockQuote,
          Table, TableToolbar,
          MediaEmbed,
          CodeBlock,
          HtmlEmbed,
          SpecialCharacters, SpecialCharactersEssentials,
          HorizontalLine,
          PageBreak,
          TextPartLanguage,
          SourceEditing, GeneralHtmlSupport,
        ],
        image: {
          toolbar: [
            'imageTextAlternative',
            'imageStyle:inline',
            'imageStyle:block',
            'imageStyle:side',
            'linkImage'
          ],
          upload: {
            types: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp']
          }
        },
        placeholder: '',
        fontFamily: {
          options: [
            'default',
            'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
          ],
          supportAllValues: true
        },
        fontSize: {
          options: [10, 12, 14, 'default', 18, 20, 22],
          supportAllValues: true
        },
        htmlSupport: {
          allow: [
            {
              name: /.*/,
              attributes: true,
              classes: true,
              styles: true
            }
          ]
        },
        htmlEmbed: {
          showPreviews: true
        },
        table: {
          contentToolbar: ['tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells']
        },
        language: {
          textPartLanguage: [
            { title: 'English', languageCode: 'en' }
          ]
        }
      })
      .then(editor => {
        console.log('Editor initialized');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error initializing editor:', error);
      });
  }

original html content
<div class="p-icon">
  <a class="plink">
    <div class="block">
      <img class="img" src="lo.svg" alt="">
      <p class="text">aaaa<br>bbbb</p>
    </div>
    <img class="arrow" src="ko.svg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

html content after enter into ckeditor
<div>
    <a class="plink"><img class="img" src="lo.svg" alt=""></a>
</div>
<p class="text">
    <a class="plink">aaaa</a><br>
    <a class="plink">bbbb</a>
</p>
<div>
    <a class="plink"><img class="arrow" src="ko.svg" alt="">&nbsp;</a>
</div>

desired html result
<div class="p-icon">
  <a class="plink">
    <div class="block">
      <img class="img" src="lo.svg" alt="">
      <p class="text">aaaa<br>bbbb</p>
    </div>
    <img class="arrow" src="ko.svg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>

I tried custom schema but it doesn't work
const customSchema = new Schema({
  blocks: {
    paragraph: true,
    div: {
      allowContentOf: '$block',
      allowWhere: '$block',
      // Disallow paragraphs within div elements
      disallowDescendants: ['paragraph']
    },
  },
  inlines: {
    // Add allowed inline elements as needed
  }
});

purpose: i want to keep the original html structure.
